# Adjusting the width of the Legend field for IE8 and lower

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I created an HTML 5 form where my legends all have background colors. My aim, which is accomplished in FireFox, Google Chrome, IE 9>, is to have text then background color extend the width of the page. The problem however is that in IE8 and lower versions it only extends to the end of the words. This is what I have so far CSS wise for my regular page:

```
   .FormArea legend
    {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   line-height: 2em;
   display: block;
       color: white;    
       background-color: #A70C1E;
       width: 95%;
       padding-left: 7px;   
    }
```

May I have some insight on how to make the necessary adjustments for IE8

Comment: Do you want a repeated text background

Comment: @ĐēēpakShãrmã no just to have the background longer. Its just a color now that sits behind the text. I just want the color to extend the width of the page

Comment: Can you please write your whole code, this piece of code is really insufficient, I can't help you, I am still not getting what you just want to ask, Please elaborate.

Comment: I think you forgot that you have assigned width to 95%, if you want to extend its background... Assign it to 100%

Answer (score 0):

I just used a padding:

```
 .FormArea legend 
    {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 1.2em;
       line-height: 2em;
       color: white;
       background-color: #A70C1E;
       width: 80px !Important;
       padding-right: 650px !important;       
       display: block;        
    }

    .FormArea legend span
   {
        width:100%;

    }
```